# Twilio Detecting When On Hold

Tags: twilio

I've used Twilio to detect whether an outbound call gets a human or answering machine response, but now I'm trying to determine when I'm on hold and when the rep eventually picks up.  The goal is to have a flag to know when I'm no longer on hold with the party I called.

Is this simply impossible with Twilio?  Do you know of any work-arounds or other services that I might explore?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into the Twilio API specific to this. You could maybe get away with playing a repeating prompt for someone to press a digit. The on hold time would never complete the prompt, but when a human picks up they would be able to and it would indicate their presence.